# How to merge resource files from other assemblies in Silverlight / wp7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

In my app i need to merge the resource file from an  external  assembly. Is it possible to do so? If the answer is yes please guide me to resolve this issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
  <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/StyleResource.Styless;component/ButtonStyle.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>  
  </Application.Resources>
```